# iPhone objective c Asyncron HTTPS request in NSThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, http, asynchronous, nsthread

I need a good solution for my little issue.

What I have at the moment:
My App works with asyncron https request very well. At the moment the app uploads an JSON object, so far so good. After that I save the object in an sqlite database.

Now I have to change to determine what the received server response code is.
I will get an response code like 000 if the uploaded data was valid, and a code like 151 if not. For that I have to wait for the server response to save the response code in the database as well.

I experimented with NSThread, too. But that didn't work out as well as I expected.

Somebody any suggestions? I mean, it should be one of the most common things ;) I just don't see it.

thx, dominik

Comment: If you guys down vote, at least give a hint for the new user what's so bad about the question so he/she may improve it.

Comment: @NickWeaver , would be nice ;)

Comment: To help you with your question: I am not getting what the main problem is. You got trouble to determine which server response actually belonged to which request?

Comment: What do you mean by 'received server response code'? HTTP status code? Or a custom protocol code?

Comment: @psoft ,it is a custom code. It is part of the returned JSON object. I need this value, because it tells me if the upload was valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use an NSOperationQueue to manage my communication. This lets you use a synchronous request instead of asynchronous, and handle the whole shebang in one method.

Example:

```
-(void)doIt {
   NSInvocationOperation *op = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doIt_) object:nil] autorelease];
   [opQueue addOperation:op];
}

-(void)doIt_ {
   NSData *data;
   NSMutableURLRequest *request;
   NSURLResponse *response = nil;
   NSError *error = nil;

   // Build request to spec

   data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:error];

   // do something with data

   [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yadda) withObject:yaddayadda waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

If you do use the asynchronous loading methods, you have to implement a delegate to catch the response data as it comes down, and do something with it when finished.

Comment: you are right, but I need a SSL connection so I have to use asynchronous requests. Syncron methods do not support HTTPS. I will have a look on the NSOperationQueue. THX

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take a look at [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) which is a wrapper for the CFNetwork API. Particularly look into the mechanism it offers for asynchronous HTTP requests, where you can define blocks to be executed once the request has completed or failed and can you can inspect the response data easily. Your code would be something like this:

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
  // add your json object to the request
  [request setCompletionBlock:^{
    int responseCode = [request responseStatusCode];
    NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
    // do whatever you want with this info
  }];
  [request setFailedBlock:^{
    NSError *error = [request error];
    // handle the error
  }];
  [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: usually I do use ASIHTTP Framework, though as far as I know it is not supported by ios5/ ARC.